# Fake Latin Generator PHP

Tags: php

*I am not asking for homework help, just a push in the right direction please!*

Recently started learning PHP at university and one of the exercises was to create a fake Latin generator.

The parameters had to be as follow:

Every word has a 1 in 10 chance of having a comma placed after it.
Every sentence has to contain between 8 and 25 words.
Every paragraph has to contain between 3 and 7 sentences.
Every page has to contain between 3 and 5 paragraphs.
Every starting sentence must start with capital letter.

My code as follow:

```
<?php
$latin_words = array("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "sed", "diam", "nonummy", "nibh", "euismod", "tincidunt", "ut",
                     "laoreet", "dolore", "magna", "aliquam", "erat", "volutpat", "ut", "wisi", "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", "nostrud",
                     "exerci", "tation", "ullamcorper", "suscipit", "lobortis", "ni", "sl", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "duis", "autem",
                     "vel", "eum", "iriure", "dolor", "in", "hendrerit", "in", "vulputate", "velit", "esse", "molestie", "consequat", "vel", "illum", "dolore", "eu",
                     "feugiat", "nulla", "facilisis", "at", "vero", "eros", "et", "accumsan", "et", "iusto", "odio", "dignissim", "qui", "blandit", "praesent", "luptatum", "zzril",
                     "delenit", "augue", "duis", "dolore", "te", "feugait", "nulla", "facilisi", "ut", "wisi", "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", "nostrud", "exerci", "tation", "ullamcorper",
                     "suscipit", "lobortis", "nisl", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "duis", "autem", "vel", "eum", "iriure", "dolor", "in", "hendrerit", "in", "vulputate",
                     "velit", "esse", "molestie", "consequat", "vel", "illum", "dolore", "eu", "feugiat", "nulla", "facilisis", "at", "vero", "eros", "et", "accumsan", "et", "iusto", "odio",
                     "dignissim", "qui", "blandit", "praesent", "luptatum", "delenit", "augue", "duis", "dolore", "te", "feugait", "nulla", "facilisi");

$max = count($latin_words);
for($pagelen = rand(3,5); $pagelen != 6; $pagelen++)
{
    $word = rand(0,$max - 1);
    for($para = rand(3,7); $para != 8; $para++)
    {
        echo ucfirst($latin_words[$word]);
        for($sentlen = rand(8,25); $sentlen != 26; $sentlen++)
        {
            $word = rand(0,$max - 1);
            echo " " . $latin_words[$word];
            for($comchance = rand(1,10); $comchance == 10; $comchance++)
            {
                echo ",";
            }
        }
        echo ". ";
    }
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

I thought i had got it all right until i started noticing that i was sometimes getting only 1 paragraph per page.

I am also not sure how to stop a comma being followed by a full stop at the end of a sentence - i read a switch might work but we hadn't covered this so i was wary about adding one in.

Any push in the right directions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your loops should probably count down instead of up.

Comment: @EvanM If the loops counted down, they would never hit the target

Comment: Maybe consider adding it as a problem on HackerRank website.

Comment: looks pretty good, you are close. Make `$para = rand(3,7); $para != 8; $para++` `$para = rand(1,5); $para != 8; $para++` and check if `$sentlen == 25` before adding a comma.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought i had got it all right until i started noticing that i was sometimes getting only 1 paragraph per page.

Consider your loop condition:

```
for($pagelen = rand(3,5); $pagelen != 6; $pagelen++)
```

This sets a random number between three and five, and increments that number until it equals six.

This means that *sometimes*, `$pagelen` will be set to `5`, the loop executes once, then `$pagelen++` sets `$pagelen` to `6`, so `$pagelen != 6` becomes false and your loop ends.

Instead you should start at zero, and increment up to a random number between 3 and 5.

```
for($i = 0, $pagelen = rand(3,5); $i < $pagelen; $i++)
```

Your other loops have the same problem. This won't completely fix it, but hopefully it will work for your push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here, hope this helps:

```
$latin_words = array("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "sed", "diam", "nonummy", "nibh", "euismod", "tincidunt", "ut",
                         "laoreet", "dolore", "magna", "aliquam", "erat", "volutpat", "ut", "wisi", "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", "nostrud",
                         "exerci", "tation", "ullamcorper", "suscipit", "lobortis", "ni", "sl", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "duis", "autem",
                         "vel", "eum", "iriure", "dolor", "in", "hendrerit", "in", "vulputate", "velit", "esse", "molestie", "consequat", "vel", "illum", "dolore", "eu",
                         "feugiat", "nulla", "facilisis", "at", "vero", "eros", "et", "accumsan", "et", "iusto", "odio", "dignissim", "qui", "blandit", "praesent", "luptatum", "zzril",
                         "delenit", "augue", "duis", "dolore", "te", "feugait", "nulla", "facilisi", "ut", "wisi", "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", "nostrud", "exerci", "tation", "ullamcorper",
                         "suscipit", "lobortis", "nisl", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "duis", "autem", "vel", "eum", "iriure", "dolor", "in", "hendrerit", "in", "vulputate",
                         "velit", "esse", "molestie", "consequat", "vel", "illum", "dolore", "eu", "feugiat", "nulla", "facilisis", "at", "vero", "eros", "et", "accumsan", "et", "iusto", "odio",
                         "dignissim", "qui", "blandit", "praesent", "luptatum", "delenit", "augue", "duis", "dolore", "te", "feugait", "nulla", "facilisi");


$max = count($latin_words);
for($pagelen = 0; $pagelen < rand(3,5); $pagelen++)
{
    for($para = 0; $para < rand(3,7); $para++)
    {
        // first word here, so the max nr. of words in the next for statement will be rand(7,24)
        echo ucfirst($latin_words[rand(0,$max - 1)]);
        $nr_words = rand(7,24);
        for($sentlen = 0; $sentlen < $nr_words; $sentlen++)
        {
            // if this is not the last word
            if($sentlen < $nr_words - 1)
            {
                $word = $latin_words[rand(0,$max - 1)];
                echo " " . $word;
                // 10% chance
                if(rand(1,10) == 1) echo ",";
            }
            else
            {
                // this is the last word so echo a full stop
                echo ". ";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```